# There should be a badge for sufficient number of accepted answers

Tags: feature-request, badges, accepted-answer

Just the other day I was counting my answers which are accepted with great enthusiasm and with a belief that there is a badge for 10 accepted answers or 30 accepted answers. But unfortunately there isn't any.

Answers getting accepted among all the good answers are probably best answers and it is an honour if your answer gets accepted. But I don't get why there is no badge like "first accepted answer" or the others what I mentioned earlier.

There a lots silly badges like...( I don't say it because you know). Most dramatic badge I find is *unsung hero* and the analogous badge in silver category. Which is definitely hard to get because why the best answer wouldn't get upvoted (I upvote first before accepting an answer for my question).

So my point is: why isn't there a badge for the first or sufficient number of accepted answers? Are there any other dynamics which I am not aware of?

Respected authority please consider this and correct me if I am wrong at any point. Thank you.

Comment: Aren't the accepts enough of a reward?  I mean what do you need in addition to accumulating green check marks?

Comment: It is not that what I need and obviously the green checks are prestigious. But the point is there should be a series of badge based on the numbers of accepted answers.

Comment: That will be ironic. Accepted Answers are already overrated, this was not their purpose. Moreover, this question belongs to the network site. I'm pretty sure someone may have already asked it there

Comment: As you can [see](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Badge+for+accepted+answer)

Comment: I don't see badges as important.  The only badges (as far as I know, since I am not interested in badges, my knowledge is very limited) that grant some kind of powers are tag gold badges.  Even if I have such badges, I'm not sure if I want to use the power.  So, I'm not sure why a gold badge for getting many answers accepted a great thing to have.  What I prefer is when a thread has a complete answer, at least one complete answer is accepted.  The accepted answer doesn't have to be mine, even if I post a complete answer there.  (Unfortunately, a lot of askers abandon their threads.)

Comment: @amWhy, Ok, my question were helpful for me. So I don't care.

Answer (score 9):

When proposing a new badge, it's always a good idea to check which kind of good behaviour it promotes that currently is not sufficiently awarded. I don't see any; the answer being accepted already gives you 15 reputation.

> Answers getting accepted among all the good answers are probably best answers

No, they're not per se. The *best* answer is (most of the time) the one with the highest score: it's more important what the community at large thinks of an answer than one user.

Comment: Yes, I understand. That is why I said "probably". But I don't know why don't you see any.... Where this site is all about "learning and help others to learn" not a so called question-answer site. There it may be that your answer is the best with respect to the number of votes. But I don't see any point if that answer doesn't get accepted or understood properly by the OP. So I guess this badges will promote the fact that be careful while answering, I don't need a "best" answer but I need an answer which I understand the most and help me learn.

Comment: *"The best answer is the one with the highest score: it's more important what the community at large thinks of an answer than one user."* No, they're not per sé. I've seen plenty of times where the highest voted answer was not the best one.

Comment: @AsafKaragila true, but it's a far better indicator than the checkmark.